# Connecting to Virtual Machine using Apache 2.4 on WIndows

Tags: windows, apache, server, ip, virtual-machine

I am currently enrolled in an Internet Tools course. Part of my course is using a VM set up by my professor for future projects.

However I am having trouble using Apache 2.4 to connect to it.
When I modify the httpd.conf to listen to the IP of the VM I am given the error

> (OS 10049)The requested address is not valid in its context.  : AH00072: make_so
>   ck: could not bind to address [IP]
>   AH00451: no listening sockets available, shutting down
>   AH00015: Unable to open logs

At first glance it seems to be an issue with Port 80 being in use however I have tried using my personal IP and it seems to work fine, even my external IP produces results.

I apologize if this all sounds very amateurish, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Apache normally listens on port 80. So does Skype, if you are running Skype try changing the port and see if Apache will run then too.

The open logs issue is going to be something else though, possibly that you need to run Apache as an Administrator.

In the start menu type cmd in the search box. Then right click on "cmd" and select run as administrator. Now navigate to your httpd.exe directory, perhaps something like:
CD C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\Apache24\bin
then run httpd.exe

You should find it runs this time as it now has permission to write to the logs.